# I can't find my context provider namespace?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Intellisense complains that it can't find the namespace `WorkorderListContext` in `WorkorderListProvider` return, but it's in the same file?

```
import { createContext } from 'react';

interface IWorkorderListContext {
    items: any[];
    setItems?: (itemsArray: []) => void;
    getItems?: () => [];
}

const defaultState = {
    items: []
};

const WorkorderListContext = createContext<IWorkorderListContext>(defaultState);

const WorkorderListProvider = ({ children }: { children: any }) => {
    return (
        <WorkorderListContext.Provider>   **<---- Error: Cannot find namespace ts(2503)**
            {children}
        </WorkorderListContext.Provider>
    )
}

export { WorkorderListProvider, WorkorderListContext };
```

Comment: What is the file name?

Comment: @SaeedHemmati its name is WorkorderListContext

Comment: Please make sure to format of the file ended with .tsx

Comment: @SaeedHemmati Thank you, add answer and Ill accept it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `.tsx` as compatible format of the file

Comment: Thanks. I wish I searched sooner because your answer came right up and was correct!